# Can a non-simple graph have a complement?

Tags: graph-theory

If so, this means that:

Two different graphs can share the same complement, however each graph cannot have two different complements.

Is this correct?

Comment: It can, but I doubt this is what you are looking for. Usually a simple undirected graph cannot have loops $v \leftrightarrow v$, but for "simple graphs with loops" complement is well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of complement of a graph is usually restricted to **simple** graphs. For example, please see the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph). (Go to the beginning of the "Formal construction" part.)

One *could* extend the definition to graphs that allow a single loop from a vertex $v$ to itself. In that case, the answer to your question would be no. With multiple loops or edges, there is no nice definition of complement.  For one thing, a desirable property of a "complement," shared by other things called complement, is that the complement of the complement of $X$ is $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the set of all possible edges can be well defined and fixed, then --relative to it-- one can define the complement, and it will be still unique (for example if $e,f$ are possible parallel edges, and $e\in\mathcal G$ but $f\notin\mathcal G$, then $f$ will be in the complement of $\mathcal G$).

Answer (score 0):

complement of a simple graph G=(V,E) is a graph having the same set of vertex but it has a complement edge of G. In multiple graph the complement does not defined, also in a graph that not multiple but has a self loops the complement of it is defined by adding a self loop of every vertex that does not have the self loop.  One example of component graph G is show below.

Answer (score 0):

yes,  A complement of a simple graph G=(V,E) is a graph having the same set of vertex but it has a complement edge of G. In multigraph ( i.e graph that has a parallel edge) the complement does not defined, also in a graph that not multigraph but has self loops the complement of it is defined by adding a self loop of every vertex that does not have the self loop.