# Can two different graphs have the same complement?

Tags: graph-theory

If two undirected graphs are identical except that one has an additional loop at vertex $A$, do they actually have the same complement?

Comment: It is a matter of **local** definition. If we allow multiple loops, then complement is not well-defined.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So you are saying that it is meaningless to talk about the complement of non-simple graph, correct? Wikipedia's definition of 'complement graph' does not seem to require that the original graph be non-simple, and I didn't want to presume.

Comment: The complement of a graph is ordinarily only **defined** for loopless graphs. So it is a strange question. Since you labelled it a homework question, I figured it was part of a homework assignment. In that case, the asker would have given his/her definition of complement, and maybe, weirdly, might have defined complement for graphs with possible loops.

Comment: If you are referring [to this,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph) go to the second paragraph, beginning of Formal Definition. It **says** simple graph.

Comment: Heh. The informal initial paragraph does not indicate that complements are meaningful only for simple graphs. As for the formal definition, I was unsure if there might be a separate definition for the complement of non-simple graphs. Hey would you please post your second comment as an answer here so that I can accept it: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/303827/21813 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically,by the terminology I know, these are *multigraphs* and not graphs. In this particular case, I don't think it applies since I think only simple graphs have complements.Think about it: the complement of this multigraph would have loops on the adjacent vertices without edges in the complement and this is clearly nonisomorphic to the complement of orginal simple graph, let alone the same complement graph. I'm not even sure the complement is well defined in the case of psuedographs.

For the case of simple graphs, the answer is clearly no since a complement graph is defined on the exact same set of vertices where the edges of the complement graph are constructed on the nonadjacent vertices of the original graph. Therefore any 2 graphs with the same complements would have to have the exact same number of vertices and the exact same adjacency relations on those vertices. Therefore, the only 2 simple graphs who have the same complement are identical. So although I'm not certain, this reasoning seems to indicate the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

The complement of a graph is only defined for simple graphs.

**Source**: M.N.S. Swamy and K. Thulasiraman: *Graphs, Networks and Algorithms* (1981): $\S 1.2$

If we extend the definition to include loopgraphs then the answer is no as well for the following reason:

Suppose $G$ has a loop at $v$ and $G'$ does not have a loop at $v$.

Then the complement of $G$ (denoted $\overline{G}$) has no loop at $v$ whereas $\overline{G'}$ does have a loop at $v$.